# OR many columns efficiently

Tags: sql, performance, indexing

Let's say I have a table with `50 columns`. I want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1=value1 OR column2=value2 OR ...
```

How can I do this efficiently?

1. I could add a bunch of `indexes` or an index across many/all columns. Would this help?
2. I could create a `secondary table` with columns (`id, field_name, field_value`) and then index on each column and now my ORs apply to just 2 columns which are indexed.
3. What else can I do?

For a bit more info:

- Rows are added pretty frequently, but rarely edited after that.
- Rows are selected several times after being added (maybe dozens but probably not hundreds).
- Table has 100,000+ rows and table scan is too slow.
- Specifically, given a row, I'll want to look up all rows that match that row on ANY column.

Comment: Not an answer but, "Table has 100,000+ rows and table scan is too slow" - must be very low spec hardware.

Comment: Show us your table definitions and some SQL that you imagine executing.

Comment: Would it be an option to redesign your table? Maybe unpivot the columns into rows?

Comment: I second thinking of a better design for this table.  OR'ing together 50 columns is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @MitchWheat The hardware here is irrelevant.  Relying on full table scans is just bad database design.

Comment: Specifically this is transaction data and I need all previous transactions that match current transaction across many attributes such as email, ip, etc.

Comment: @Mike Brant: I'm fully aware of that. If the poster's query is not selective enough then an index probably won't be used anyway. Also, Hardware is never irrelevant! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run into scenarios like this, it typically indicates that there may be room for normalizing the table (your scenario B). It would be hard to know without further information on what data your columns actually hold and what your overall table access pattern is.

That being said, without any sort of table structure change, you would just need to have an index on each column that you might want to query against, so as to prevent a full table scan.

Comment: The data is mostly strings say size 10-20. If I add a bunch of indexes will that work for the big OR queries (question 1). How bad is 30-50 indexes at write time?

Comment: @user1096773 It is certainly not ideally to have that many indexes on a table that will have a significant number of writes on it. It will make the write operation take longer than it normally would.  And data storage requirements will certainly be much greater (if that matter to you). However, the indexes can certainly optimize your "OR" query to where it doesn't require a full table scan. But my main instinct in such a case would be to look at revising the schema to look for a different approach.

Comment: @MikeBryant if I consider expanding the columns into rows then I guess it's a choice between (a) 20 indexes and 20 indexed queries to search, or (b) 20 writes per new row, and 1 indexed query on a table with 20 times more rows. Not totally sure which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside a discussion of changing your database design...

---

A combined index (an index on many or most of the columns referenced in your query) isn't going to be of help for your query, which has a bunch of `OR`'d `colN = 'foo'` predicates. MySQL is not going use that index to satisfy your query. Even if it were to use the index, there would still be other columns in the underlying table that need to be checked on essentially every row, so MySQL is very likely just to visit all the data pages and not use an index at all.  (If you happen to have a GROUP BY or ORDER BY in your query, MySQL might be able to use the index to optimize those operations, especially if it was a "covering" index that included EVERY column referenced by your query.

On the other hand, IF you had a separate, individual index on EVERY column (as a leading column in the index) that was checked with an `OR colN = 'foo' OR colN = 'bar'`, it is possible that MySQL would consider using an "index merge" plan for your query.

But it would have to be an index on EVERY column.  If your query is checking even just ONE column that is not a leading column in ANY index, then MySQL would have no choice but to examine every row in the table. So having separate indexes on "many" columns will not help your query, because it's very likely that NONE of the indexes will be used.

Even if you did have a separate index for every single one of the boatload of columns being reference, it's likely that MySQL's estimate of the total number of rows being returned (combined from each index) is too large, and MySQL is likely to decide that an "index merge" is too expensive, and opt for a full table scan instead.

---

In summary, your only two choices for indexes to help your query (and neither of them is a really good choice) would be:

1) a "covering index" that has leading columns that can be used to satisfy a GROUP BY or an ORDER BY clause (avoiding a "Using filesort" operation"

2) separate, individual indexes on EVERY column (as a leading column) that is checked by an `OR colN = 'literal'` predicate in your query

But again, neither of those is likely to be a good choice.